# Cant get view to load up when running app

Tags: android, xml, view, android-layout

Im writing my first app for android and i cant get the xml layout to load up. Ive looked at references and cant seem to find the problem. The code compiles and runs but all that shows up on the screen is a black page with the status and title bar at the top.

Any ideas

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View cancelButton= findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View sevenButton= findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sevenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View fourButton= findViewById(R.id.button3);
    fourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View oneButton= findViewById(R.id.button4);
    oneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View zeroButton= findViewById(R.id.button5);
    zeroButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View divideButton= findViewById(R.id.button6);
    divideButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View eightButton= findViewById(R.id.button7);
    eightButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View fiveButton= findViewById(R.id.button8);
    fiveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View twoButton= findViewById(R.id.button9);
    twoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View pointButton= findViewById(R.id.button10);
    pointButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View timesButton= findViewById(R.id.button11);
    timesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View nineButton= findViewById(R.id.button12);
    nineButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View sixButton= findViewById(R.id.button13);
    sixButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View threeButton= findViewById(R.id.button14);
    threeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View shiftButton= findViewById(R.id.button15);
    shiftButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View backButton= findViewById(R.id.button16);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View addButton= findViewById(R.id.button17);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View minusButton= findViewById(R.id.button18);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View equalsButton= findViewById(R.id.button19);
    equalsButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}
```

UPDATE
here is the code for the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/main" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:background="@drawable/trondroid">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="6dip" 
              android:layout_marginTop="100dip">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                      android:layout_width="76dip" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:text="c" 
                    android:id="@+id/button1" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="7" 
                    android:id="@+id/button2" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="4" 
                    android:id="@+id/button3" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="1" 
                    android:id="@+id/button4" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="0" 
                    android:id="@+id/button5" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
                      android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                      android:layout_width="75dip">
            <Button android:text="/" 
                    android:id="@+id/button6" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="8" 
                    android:id="@+id/button7" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="5" 
                    android:id="@+id/button8" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="2" 
                    android:id="@+id/button9" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="." 
                    android:id="@+id/button10" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
                      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                      android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:layout_width="75dip">
            <Button android:text="*" 
                    android:id="@+id/button11" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="9" 
                    android:id="@+id/button13" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="6" 
                    android:id="@+id/button14" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="3" 
                    android:id="@+id/button15" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="" 
                    android:id="@+id/button16" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                      android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" 
                      android:orientation="vertical" 
                      android:layout_width="75dip">
            <Button android:text="" 
                    android:id="@+id/button12" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="+" 
                    android:id="@+id/button17" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="-" 
                    android:id="@+id/button18" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="75dip">
            </Button>
            <Button android:text="=" 
                    android:id="@+id/button19" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Strip out your code until it starts working. Then start putting things back in one by one until it breaks. easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there :) for an OnClickListener you actually have to provide an OnClickListener implementation. You're passing "this" does that mean your activity als implements View.OnClickListener? Because if it does not - the above code won't work. But something else: Your layout (if you have defined it in XML should show up regardless of whether the OnClickListener have been set. Could you please post your XMl layout to?

Cheers,
Ready4Android

P.s. If this really is your first app you might want to start with some tutorials first :) you'll pick up a lot of basic stuff there which will help you getting started. A nice place for getting started are the official [developer pages of Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Comment: I implemented OnClickListener already, and i posted the xml file.